# xlsx package:Write excel file to a custom path

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I am trying to write an array of objects to excel using `xlsx`  package.

I want to write the file to a path instead of current directory

```
 const fileName ='ouptputs/test.xlsx'
const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                
 XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, workSheet,fileName);
 const s = XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName,{
     type:"file"
 });
```

But executing this i m getting the error

> Sheet name cannot contain : \ / ? *

So how do i specify the path instead of generating the file to current dir

I searched in their doc https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#writing-options but couldn't able to find the documentation about the custom path

Comment: The error is coming from `XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, workSheet,fileName);`.  If you correct the worksheet name then you should be able to write to the path you're after

Comment: Thanks got the issue , one minor question what will be the sheet name if no name is given??

Comment: Give it a name, just don't use the variable filename since it has a slash in the path

Comment: e.g. `XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, workSheet,'Sheet1');`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you pass the string as fileName to the writeFile function it tries to find the file in the current directory with the name you provided but it contains "/" which can not be present in the file name because of which it causing the error.

**So the solution is to create the path by using the "path" library, See below code for example**

```
const path = require('path');

// You may need to use relative path in join function depending upon the working file location
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'ouptputs/test.xlsx'); // __dirname -> returns the current path of the working file
const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, workSheet, 'Sheet1'); // Sheet1 is the name of sheet that is created inside workbook
const s = XLSX.writeFile(wb, filePath, {
        bookType: 'xlsx',
        type: 'file'
});
```

Hope it will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)